# Auto Responder for custom Web to Case

Tags: email, web2case

We recently put together a small APEX Controller with VF page to act as a Web-to-Case form.  It's running on a VF Site, and embedded in an iframe into our main website.  This was done to allow users to create a Case and upload files (as ContentDocuments with Links to the Case).

At this point, the Case is being created and the file uploads handled.  However, there are no auto-response emails sent.  Apparently there is a configuration our admins tweaked to send a "case received" email when a case is created.  The standard Web2Case setup triggered these (but of course doesn't allow file uploads).

I think the relevant code is:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
dmlOpts.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;
if (emailIsContact) {
    dmlOpts.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = true;
}
WebCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
//..
INSERT WebCase;
```

We're checking if the entered email is on a Contact record, and if so then a) that contact is associated with the case, and b) it's flagged and we set the triggerOtherEmail flag (setting this for emails of non-contacts seems to be a problem).

However, we're not seeing any auto-response emails go out (we've used several test contact of internal users).

Answer (score 0):

The sobject.setOptions method seems a bit flaky (I've been meaning to ask someone about that). Try using the Database.insert(record, options) method instead:

```
Database.insert(WebCase, dmlOpts);
```

Comment: It took a while to get our admin to try out the new code.  Unfortunately it's seeming to function the same as before.  At this point I really suspect something possibly related to permissions for the anon Sites user.

Comment: @Robert Odd. Time to dig through some debug logs, it sounds like.